# Server response array is empty for a specified user

Tags: php, android, mysql

i am trying to get data using json for a specified user who logged in.
the data is displayed in an array ..i get empty array when i run in query:

```
"select * from 'table' where username=".$_POST['username'];
```

`$_POST['username']` gets it data from a plain text that contains the username for the user who logged in.

Can any one please try to figure why the array is empty although that the plain text displays the username !

These are my java classes :

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Fruit,String> {
Context ctx;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Fruit>arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
public BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    activity=(Activity)ctx;
}
String json_string = "http://www.androidiut20.netai.net/getmarkdetails.php";
// String json_string1 = "androidiut20.netai.net/login.php";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Fruit... values) {
    arrayList.add(values[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   //Intent i = new Intent(ctx,test.class);
  // i.putExtra("userName",result);
  //  ctx.startActivity(i);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  String username = params[0];

    try {
        URL url = new URL(json_string);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

       httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();

       bufferedWriter.close();
       outputStream.close();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
        String response2 = "";
        String line2 = "";
        while ((line2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response2 += line2;


        }

        URL url1 = new URL(json_string);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();


        InputStream inputStream1 = httpURLConnection1.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream1));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line1;
        while ((line1= bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line1 + "\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection1.disconnect();


        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count=0;
        while(count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit(JO.getString("name"),JO.getString("username"),JO.getDouble("mark"));
            publishProgress(fruit);

        }
        //return response2;

        Log.d("JSON STRING", json_string);
        return response2;



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return  null;

}
```

}

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
private static final int TYPE_HEAD=0;
private static final int TYPE_LIST=1;
ArrayList<Fruit>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Fruit>arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return  recyclerViewHolder;

    }
    else
    if(viewType==TYPE_LIST)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return  recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    return  null;



}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.viewType==TYPE_LIST)
    {
        Fruit fruit =arrayList.get(position-1);
        holder.Name.setText(fruit.getName());
        holder.Calories.setText(fruit.getCalories());
        holder.Fat.setText(String.valueOf(fruit.getFat()));
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size()+1;    }
public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView Name,Calories,Fat;
    int viewType;
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view,int viewType)
    {
        super(view);
        if(viewType==TYPE_LIST)
        {
            Name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Calories=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calories);
            Fat=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fat);
            this.viewType=TYPE_LIST;
        }
        else if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD)
        {
            this.viewType=TYPE_HEAD;
        }


    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0)
        return TYPE_HEAD;
    return TYPE_LIST;
}
```

}

**getmarksdetails.php**

```
$host="//";
$user="//";
$password="//";
$db="//";

$con= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
$username=$_POST['username'];





$query="select name,username,mark from user_info where username like '$username'";           


$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$response=array();


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   

array_push($response,array('name'=>$row[0],'username'=>$row[1],'mark'=>$row[2]));
} 

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode(array('server_response'=>$response));
```

**logcat:D/JSON STRING: {"server_response":[]}**

Comment: Do you get JSON back if you try your link in your web browser?

Comment: I got this : server_response":[]

Comment: Then you have issues either with your request or with the server itself. Look into that first.

Comment: How to ensure that $_POST['username']  contains the data from the plain text?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP so I can't help you there, however, for testing purposes, you should just try to hardcode the user's name to see if at least your request is working correctly.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Since you're already familiar with the Android framework, you might want to try out one of the popular [development frameworks for PHP](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to avoid having to work at such a low level. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is very well documented and beginner friendly. It will help give your server side code a lot more organization and functionality with significantly less work than using only core PHP.

Comment: Thank you a lot Tadman ! i will try that